# Where to find AppCompatPreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying android v7 support library and I have this on my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.0'
```

I am getting class not found error for `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`.

I can copy the class from [here](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary/blob/master/material_preferences_library/src/main/java/com/lb/material_preferences_library/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java) but am not sure if that is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is PreferenceActivity (android.preference.PreferenceActivity).

AppCompatPreferenceActivity is not a part of v7 support library, though it is a part of demos, look into [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/nougat-release/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java).

You can also copy the same from [Here](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary/blob/master/material_preferences_library/src/main/java/com/lb/material_preferences_library/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java).

Comment: hmm ... so copying the class is the solution?

Comment: Yes, as it is not a part of library.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the gradle imports to the latest [versions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a project where Android Studio automatically added this file when adding a SettingsActivity through the wizard.

However, at a later point I repeated the same exact steps for another project and this class was NOT added automatically. So I copied the file from one project to the other, and problem solved (the file is `AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java` located in the main folder).